# How can I copy files from filepath mentioned in cells in excel in my server using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

I am trying to build a bulk upload functionality on an ASP .NET page. this is required to upload questions and answers in a SQL table. There can be images as well in the question and the answers. For those images, the path to image can be specified.

Is it possible to copy the images from end user's machine to the server and then move these images into the SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

> "Is it possible to copy the images from end user's machine to the
>   server"

Not unless you provide a file input control explicitly on the page and the user puts the necessary file(s) into that control and they get uploaded along with your other data.

Your server does not have access to the user's machine. In fact it almost certainly doesn't even know exactly which machine the request came from. It certainly doesn't have access to any of its disk drives, unless the machine has its own specific public IP address and appallingly lax firewall and security settings.

In fact even your webpage, when it's rendered in the user's browser - which is on their machine - doesn't have access to the disk (think of the implications if a webpage could randomly read files from your disk!) except via a file upload control where the user has to specifically choose which files to send to the server.